# Navigate to parent path from router outlet (NG5)

Tags: angular, angular-router

**Problem**

Trying to navigate from `http://localhost:4200/#/place/(popup:tabs-modal)`
*(an outlet)* to `http://localhost:4200/#/place/someId`

Notice that the outlet is basically a child route to "place".

**What I can do**

I can close the outlet, and just end up on: `http://localhost:4200/#/place`: `this.router.navigate(['place', { outlets: { popup: null } }]);`

**Oh then its easy right?**

`this.router.navigate(['place', 'someId', { outlets: { popup: null } }]);`should then navigate me to `http://localhost:4200/#/place/someId` right?

Wrong. The router generates a non-sensical route for me: `"/place/(someId//popup:tabs-modal)"`

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just buggy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.router.navigate(['/', 'place', { outlets: { popup: null } }]);
```

You are required to lead from the root path

EDIT:

There is an outstanding issue on angular router hopefully fixed with this pull request: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22394

The issue relating to empty router outlets. You also need to know that relative paths are only relative to the router tree (ActiveRoutes) and not the URL. With that in mind, I've created a helper function to get around the issue until its fixed in Angular 6.

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
/**
 *
 * Angular Relative path tempory solution. Angular doesn't like empty paths.
 * Should be fixed in version 6 Pull request 22394
 * https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22394
 *
 * Angular Issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13011#issuecomment-274414952
 *
 * Before removing check relative paths work on named outlet. Using Navigate on named
 * outlet currently relates to secondary routes (outlet:'route/test)
 * this meant breaking out wasn't possiable using ../../ like documented in
 * angular own documentation
 *
 * key Information: This is relative to routes like anuglar intended NOT URL path
 *
 * Bug only relates to going to parent and down the tree
 *
 * @export NavigateByRelative
 * @param {string} path
 * @param {Router} router
 * @param {ActivatedRoute} route
 *
 */
export function NavigateByRelative(path: string, router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {

    /**
     * Relative paths should always start with '../' as per angular documentation
     * https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation
     */
    if (path.startsWith('../')) {
        // split path into multiple paths
        const paths = path.split('/');

        // minus 1 on length as we gurantee need the last index
        const totalPathToLastIndex = paths.length - 1;

        // current index so we can start at this later on
        let currentPathIndex;

        // Relative to is so we get to the correct parent
        let relativeTo = route;

        // Check their is a parent and the current path still intended to go back up the tree
        for (currentPathIndex = 0;
            currentPathIndex < totalPathToLastIndex
            && relativeTo.parent !== undefined
            && paths[currentPathIndex] === '..';
            currentPathIndex++
        ) {
            relativeTo = relativeTo.parent;
        }

        // Navigate starting at the the currentpathIndex and relative to the current parent
        router.navigate([...paths.splice(currentPathIndex )], { relativeTo });

    } else {
        // else use navigation as normal as this should work correctly
        router.navigate([path]);
    }
}
```

**Update: 23/10/2018**
Sorry for the delay. As of angular 6 the issue with router navigation has now been resolved

**Update: 02/04/2019**
Angular 7+ has introduce the bug again.

Comment: Tried that, made no difference sadly.

Comment: Hi @DarkNeuron. I've updated the post with a helper function to fix this issue,

Comment: Thanks for maintaining your answer! I'll stick with `navigateByUrl` for now since it's just a one-liner, and revisit the issue when NG6 is out. Thanks again

Comment: HI @DarkNeuron.

Sorry for the delay in getting back. As of angular 6.1 the router issue has now been resolved

Comment: HI @DarkNeuron Further update. Angular 7 has reintroduce the bug

Comment: @DarkNeuron I've not tested it again since. I believe it's fixed as of version 8

Comment: Thanks for the updates! However we've scrapped angular for now - too many weird bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to make `.navigate()` work, and ended up using `router.navigateByUrl('/place/someId')` instead. A simple solution that eluded me.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is bad practice since you surely don't want to navigateByUrl whenever you want to close your popup or whatever. Best thing to do is something like this in your router:

```
{
        path: 'place/:someid',
        component: PlacePageComponent,
        resolve: {someid: SomeIDResolver},
        children: [
            {
                path: 'tabs-modal/:maybenextidhere',
                outlet: 'popup',
                component: TabsModalComponent,
                resolve: {maybenextidhere: MaybeNextIDResolver},
            },
        ]
    },
```

And then here comes the trick. In your function where you want to close the popup, you want to call something like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['./', {outlets: { popup: null}}], {relativeTo: this.route.firstChild.firstChild});
```

Comment: You not navigating by URL with the solution. It's navigating via ActiveRoutes not the URL as angular own docs described. Looks like this bug keeps coming back

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue. The thing is that I wanted to be able to use my component in any depth. So https://stackoverflow.com/a/50976238/1617590 solution led me to create a slightly different and more flexible approach.

Helper method looks through main  `ActivatedRoute` and returns the `ActivatedRoute` needed for `relativeTo` property to properly navigate out of the secondary outlet.

```js
private getRelativeTo(
  obj: ActivatedRoute,
  callback: (lastFirstChild: ActivatedRoute) => void
) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (key === 'outlet') {
      if (obj[key] === PRIMARY_OUTLET) {
        const fChild = obj.firstChild;
        const nextFChild = fChild ? fChild!.firstChild : undefined;
        if (fChild && nextFChild) {
          nextFChild.outlet === 'modal' // name of your secondary outlet
            ? callback(fChild) // found child component with named outlet
            : this.getRelativeTo(fChild, callback) // not found, go deeper
        } else {
          // No named child outlet found so just return back.
          callback(this.route);
        }
      } else {
        // First child is not the primary, so just return back.
        callback(this.route);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And this is how I use it to close my modal:

```js
...

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {}

closeModal() {
  this.getRelativeTo(this.route, (lastFirstChild) => {
    this.router.navigate(['./', { outlets: { modal: null } }], {
      replaceUrl: true,
      relativeTo: lastFirstChild,
    });
  });
}
```

This approach helped me to properly navigate out from child routes with named auxiliary outlets when used on the same level as the primary outlet as well as when used as a child component.

Hope that helps.